# I can't do check box by using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I tried to do check box by using Python Selenium but
I got the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The element is wrong but I'm not sure where it is.
This is how HTML is.

```
<div _ngcontent-yfw-c1="" class="col-md-12 text-center form-group mt-4 p-2" id="iAcceptCheckboxLabel">
　<input _ngcontent-yfw-c1="" class="checkbox ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" id="iAcceptCheckbox" name="checkbox" 　　　　　type="checkbox">
　<label _ngcontent-yfw-c1="" class="font-weight-normal" for="iAcceptCheckbox"> I accept the 
　　<a _ngcontent-yfw-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" href="/terms" id="terms-link" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>　　　　　　　　　　
　</label>
</div>
```

I did python like this.

```
# I accept the terms and conditions
check = driver.find_element_by_class_name("checkbox")
check.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Added

Finally, this code succeeded.

```
check = driver.find_element_by_id("iAcceptCheckbox")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",check)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("iAcceptCheckbox")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

### Update:

Try such approach

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def scroll_element_into_view(driver, element):
    y = element.location['y']
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, {0})'.format(y))
    
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='iAcceptCheckboxLabel']")
scroll_element_into_view(driver, element)
element.click()
```

The element maybe inside a frame, so you have to switch to that frame first to be able to deal with the element `driver.switch_to.frame`

Comment: Thank you but I got the error like this "move target out of bounds".

Comment: Maybe you need to put some waiting. Can you share the url?

Comment: @ligtning Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it clicked "terms and conditions". It's not "Check Box".

Comment: I can't test on my side so try using ID instead `element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "iAcceptCheckbox")`

Comment: @ligtning Have you tried the last reply ..? Please can you mark the solution that has worked for you?

Comment: Thank you I tried it but same error. selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @ligtning There are many solutions provided in your question, what is the solution that worked for you? I am curious to know.

Comment: I tried everything but all things don't work unfortunately

Comment: That's weird. I suggest sharing the URL or at least the whole HTML source!!

Comment: You are right. I should do it. Now I'm asking the client again that I can share it or not. I'm waiting for a response. Once they permit, I will share the URL.

Comment: @ligtning Have you tried PDHide solution? I think it is a great idea and a great solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it clicked "terms and conditions". It's not "Check Box".

Comment: Can you share the whole HTML source? Maybe this helpful for all of us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229083/discussion-between-ligtning-and-yasserkhalil).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share it because of the client. sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.

Comment: Glad you can solve it. If you see the first answer I gave you, you will find the near solution you used :)

Answer (score 0):

Click the label for the input tag.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='iAcceptCheckbox']"))).click()
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, but it clicked "terms and conditions". It's not "Check Box".

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please click the `input` tag.

Try the following selector and use `ActionChains`:

```
check = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#iAcceptCheckboxLabel input#iAcceptCheckbox')
#edited here
driver.execute("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", check)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(check).click(check).perform()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the error "selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds"

Comment: @ligtning see the updated answer with added `driver.execute("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", check)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error.     elif 'sessionId' not in params:
TypeError: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable

Comment: @ligtning with the above code, please change locator with `.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="iAcceptCheckbox"]')` or `.find_element_by_css_selector('div#iAcceptCheckboxLabel')`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Click the div element for label

**As the div element is displayed in foreground. You cannot click the input directly as the click will be intercepted by this div tag**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='iAcceptCheckboxLabel']"))).click()
```

**Imports**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

### Update

```
check= WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='iAcceptCheckboxLabel']")))
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(check,1,2).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Checking a check box in Selenium should be easy, I think you just have a small syntax error

```
check = driver.find_element_by_class_name("checkbox")
check.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

> Try the following...

```
check = driver.find_element_by_name("checkbox")
check.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

> I think the problem is just that you had "driver.find_element_by_class_name

> But you specified the name attribute. Not the class attribute

Comment: Thank you. I think so too but I got the error "Message: element not interactable".

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

check = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "iAcceptCheckbox"))
```

When ever you can, try to use by_id because it is the fastest, then name, and then xpath or css. For the not interactble element use explicit wait.

Comment: Thank you but I did it already and the same error occurred.

Comment: @ligtning have edited my answer. Try explicit wait because you are getting ElementNotInteractableException.

Comment: @ligtning If this helped you, pleas mark answer as accepted.

Comment: I got the error like this. I don't know why...
check = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "iAcceptCheckbox")))
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: @ligtning Just add 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: Thanks but I got  "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Comment: @ligtning Were you able to click it manualy? You can extand wait period for 10 sec, but it is probably something else. WebDriverWait(driver, 10)....

Comment: Yes, I can do it manually. Maybe I miss chose the element.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, finally, I solved it by myself.
I added the code.